# opencv meanStdDev for nonzero values

Tags: python, opencv, math

I'd like to calculate mean and stats for an image with ignoring zeros. Since I didn't figure out how to use the mask parameter for this in cv2.meanStdDev i thought i could fix up things with a bit of math.

According to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/3rdparty/carotene/src/meanstddev.cpp

The standarddeviation is calculated in accordance with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation as:

```
f64 stddev = sqrt(std::max(fsqsum * itotal - mean * mean, 0.0));
```

The following code now tries go "Work back on that formula" to fix the result for the values that were added for all the zeros that should not be accounted for

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

def test_Stats():    
    h=2
    w=2
    channels=3

    image=np.zeros((h,w,channels), np.uint8)
    image[0,0]=(100,50,200)
    image[0,1]=(120,60,220)
    (means, stds) = cv2.meanStdDev(image)
    gmean,bmean,rmean=means.flatten()
    gstds,bstds,rstds=stds.flatten()
    print ("means %.1f %.1f %.1f " % (gmean,bmean,rmean))
    print ("stds  %.1f %.1f %.1f " % (gstds,bstds,rstds))
    b = image[:,:,0]
    g = image[:,:,1]
    r = image[:,:,2]
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    pixels=h*w
    nonzerotupel= cv2.countNonZero(b),cv2.countNonZero(g),cv2.countNonZero(r)
    nonzero=max(nonzerotupel)
    print ("%d pixel %d non-zero" % (pixels,nonzero))
    factor=pixels/nonzero
    fgmean=gmean*factor
    fbmean=bmean*factor
    frmean=rmean*factor
    print ("non-zero means %.1f %.1f %.1f" % (fgmean,fbmean,frmean))
    fsqsumb=(bstds*bstds+bmean*bmean)/pixels
    fsqsumg=(gstds*gstds+gmean*gmean)/pixels
    fsqsumr=(rstds*rstds+rmean*rmean)/pixels
    fstdsb=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumb*nonzero-fbmean*fbmean,0))
    fstdsg=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumg*nonzero-fgmean*fgmean,0))
    fstdsr=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumr*nonzero-frmean*frmean,0))
    print ("non-zero stds %.1f %.1f %.1f" % (fstdsb,fstdsg,fstdsr))
```

Running it with:

```
test_Stats()
```

gives:

```
means 55.0 27.5 105.0 
stds  55.5 27.7 105.2 
4 pixel 2 non-zero
non-zero means 110.0 55.0 210.0
non-zero stds 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

so it looks like I made some mistake. The expected result for the non-zero stds would be 10.0,5.0,10.0 with this example

**What would the fix be?**

**What would improve this code further after fixing?**

Comment: Please note that in the meantime I switched to calculating things from histograms. See https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/play-chess-with-a-webcam/blob/master/pcwawc/histogram.py For the histograms it's possible to change the range and ignore the zeros in the first place. That's much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the mistake. 
The answer to the first question: **What would the fix be?** is below.

Reason: itotal in the c++ version means "inverse total" - 1/total. I had assumed it would mean "integer total". So the pixel nonzero adjustments need to be fixed. The result is now

```
means 55.00 27.50 105.00 
stds  55.45 27.73 105.24 
4 pixel 2 non-zero
non-zero means 110.00 55.00 210.00
fsqsum 6100.00 24400.00 88400.00
non-zero stds 5.00 10.00 10.00
```

which looks o.k. Question 2: **What would improve this code further after fixing?** 
is still open

```
def test_Stats():    
    h=2
    w=2
    channels=3

    image=np.zeros((h,w,channels), np.uint8)
    image[0,0]=(100,50,200)
    image[0,1]=(120,60,220)
    (means, stds) = cv2.meanStdDev(image)
    gmean,bmean,rmean=means.flatten()
    gstds,bstds,rstds=stds.flatten()
    print ("means %.2f %.2f %.2f " % (gmean,bmean,rmean))
    print ("stds  %.2f %.2f %.2f " % (gstds,bstds,rstds))
    b = image[:,:,0]
    g = image[:,:,1]
    r = image[:,:,2]
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    pixels=h*w
    nonzerotupel= cv2.countNonZero(b),cv2.countNonZero(g),cv2.countNonZero(r)
    nonzero=max(nonzerotupel)
    print ("%d pixel %d non-zero" % (pixels,nonzero))
    factor=pixels/nonzero
    fgmean=gmean*factor
    fbmean=bmean*factor
    frmean=rmean*factor
    print ("non-zero means %.2f %.2f %.2f" % (fgmean,fbmean,frmean))
    fsqsumb=(bstds*bstds+bmean*bmean)*pixels
    fsqsumg=(gstds*gstds+gmean*gmean)*pixels
    fsqsumr=(rstds*rstds+rmean*rmean)*pixels
    print ("fsqsum %.2f %.2f %.2f" % (fsqsumb,fsqsumg,fsqsumr))
    fstdsb=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumb/nonzero-fbmean*fbmean,0))
    fstdsg=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumg/nonzero-fgmean*fgmean,0))
    fstdsr=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumr/nonzero-frmean*frmean,0))
    print ("non-zero stds %.2f %.2f %.2f" % (fstdsb,fstdsg,fstdsr))
```

as a function:

```
def fixMeans(self,means,stds,pixels,nonzero):
        """ fix the zero based means to nonzero based see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58891531/1497139"""
        gmean,bmean,rmean=means.flatten()
        gstds,bstds,rstds=stds.flatten()
        if Color.debug:
            print ("means %.2f %.2f %.2f " % (gmean,bmean,rmean))
            print ("stds  %.2f %.2f %.2f " % (gstds,bstds,rstds))
        factor=pixels/nonzero
        fgmean=gmean*factor
        fbmean=bmean*factor
        frmean=rmean*factor
        if Color.debug:
            print ("non-zero means %.2f %.2f %.2f" % (fgmean,fbmean,frmean))
        fsqsumb=(bstds*bstds+bmean*bmean)*pixels
        fsqsumg=(gstds*gstds+gmean*gmean)*pixels
        fsqsumr=(rstds*rstds+rmean*rmean)*pixels
        if (Color.debug):
            print ("fsqsum %.2f %.2f %.2f" % (fsqsumb,fsqsumg,fsqsumr))
        fstdsb=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumb/nonzero-fbmean*fbmean,0))
        fstdsg=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumg/nonzero-fgmean*fgmean,0))
        fstdsr=math.sqrt(max(fsqsumr/nonzero-frmean*frmean,0))   
        if Color.debug:
            print ("non-zero stds %.2f %.2f %.2f" % (fstdsb,fstdsg,fstdsr))
        fixedmeans=fgmean,fbmean,frmean
        fixedstds=fstdsb,fstdsg,fstdsr
        return fixedmeans,fixedstds
```